# Prove this simple graph is not planar.

Tags: graph-theory

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upWTS.png)

I need to show this graph is not planar. I've attempted to find $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraphs but haven't been successful yet. It's possible but unlikely this graph *is* planar but I haven't been able to draw it as a plane graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw this graph without vertex 10 or 15. Then think of constricting the path 4-20-5-30 down to a single vertex.

Remember, you don't need to have $K_{5}$ or $K_{3,3}$ as *subgraphs*, only a subgraph that is a *subdivision* of $K_{5}$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: I quickly solved it after trying what you suggested. I only remembered that it needed to be a subdivision, not subgraph after I checked for K5. Thanks.